# Efficient maximum independent set within a graph with a maximum degree of 2

Tags: c++, algorithm, set, max

The limitations are of 100.000 (10^5) nodes and 2 or less edges per node

How could we get a maximum independent set for this graph in O(n) or O(n log n) time? Otherwise, it goes out on time. By the way, i just need to know the amount of points integrating the set, not necessarily the set of points itself.

I know of the greedy aproximation that works on O(n) which is picking nodes with the lowest number of degree, adding them to our set and then removing all its neighbors, repeating that until the graph is empty, and this aproximation works for many cases. Thing is, with these restrictions, isn't there any algorithm that always work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On that class of graphs, if you greedily choose the node with the lowest degree and delete it and its neighbors, then you'll get an optimal solution, in linear time.

Comment: Just edited my post, and i believe it, but why does it always work with a degree of 2? I thought that greedy method always worked as an aproximation. Thank you for your answer

Comment: @JuanIgnacioSuarez Nodes of degree 0 or 1 are always a safe choice regardless of the graph class. If all nodes have degree 2, then you have a union of disjoint cycles, and all of the choices are symmetric.